# Simple Fedora POP3/IMAP Server. HOWTO?

Tags: email, fedora, imap, pop3

I have an old PC running text-mode FC5. I need to read the mail sent just for the root account (from crond, logwatch, ...etc) in my Windows POP3/IMAP client. What is the simplest server to install and configure in my case? I prefer FC5 native rpm.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FC5 is ancient, and there aren't likely to be many guides around on what you're looking for. I recommend you upgrade to at *least* F12 (or even CentOS 5 if you want off the upgrade treadmill) and then use dovecot as a POP3/IMAP4 server, after aliasing the mail for root to your user account.

Comment: OK, this mean dovecot with aliasing root to a user account is all what I need, right? Why not installing dovecot on FC5? does it suffer from any security issue?

Comment: Newer versions of dovecot are much faster. But yes, you could get away with installing it on FC5 if you had to.

Comment: Thanks for your support! It is not the first time :)